# «Div» по центру, выравнивание div

Tags: html, css

**Всем отличного настроения, ну вот у меня с настроением не очень. т.к не получается разместить div по центру.**

Нашел в инете несколько способов как это сделать. на примере все работает, но вот для моего случая ни в какую не хочет. <br/>
Не могу понять что не так.

```
 <td class="leftCol">
    <div class="centrirov" arrow="firstArrow" align="center"><div class="text" >Text</div></div>
    <div class="centrirov" arrow="secondArrow"><div class="text"> Text  </div> </div>
    <div class="centrirov" arrow="thirdArrow"><div class="text"> Text  </div> </div>
    <div class="centrirov"arrow="fourthArrow"><div class="text"> Text  </div> </div>
        </td>
```

Стили

```
#middle .leftCol{
width:700px;
padding-left:20px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid #000;
}

#middle .leftCol .centrirov .active{
width:144px;
height:110px;
background:url(/i/buttonActive.png) no-repeat;
/*margin-top:-6px;*/
color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle
}

.enabled{
cursor:pointer;
}

#middle .leftCol .centrirov .active .text{
color:#fff;
}

#middle .leftCol .centrirov .text{
background:none;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
}

#middle .leftCol .centrirov {
background:url(/i/button.png) no-repeat;
width:129px;
height:100px;
float:left;
margin-right:28px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#bebcbc;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Comment: При чём тут эти стили? Какие блоки нужно отцентрировать?

Comment: [http://hashcode.ru/questions/78265/как-сделать-что-бы-див-был-посередине](http://hashcode.ru/questions/78265/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

Такой громоздкий код, для такого примера. Не хочу разьиратся что и где нужно выровнять. В общим вот: для выравнивания дива с **фиксированной шириной**

```
div.center {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: <div class="text" >Text</div> нужно выравнять по центру leftCol div

Comment: а самостоятельно из приведенного ответа не извлечете решение? =\

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="text" align='center'>` - почему нет?

Comment: Потому что невалидно как минимум. И не везде работает.

Comment: Да этот способ не работает,и не нашел нормального полноценного способа решения данной задачи

Answer (score 1):

> Не могу понять что не так.

Не так здесь

```
#middle .leftCol .centrirov {
  ...
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  ...
}
```

Эти свойства не сочетаются!

**Решение:**
Из стиля для `#middle .leftCol .centrirov` нужно убрать

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Каждый `div.text` обернуть ещё в один `div` и задать этому `div`'ву стиль

```
#middle .leftCol .centrirov > div {
  width: 129px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

PS:
Кто не понял, челу нужно было вертикальное выравнивание `div.text`.